# For what percentage of numbers does this proof of Goldbach's conjecture hold?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, pigeonhole-principle, goldbachs-conjecture

### Question

For what percentage of numbers does the below inequality hold?

$$ \pi(2m) > \frac{\phi(2 m) -1}{2} $$

where $m$ is not a prime or $1$, $\pi(m)$ is the number of primes less than $m$ and $\phi$ is the Euler totient function.

### Background + Proof

I was trying to prove Goldbach's Conjecture are realised I could do it for certain numbers.

Consider the following where $m$ is not a prime:

$$ (2m)! =  2m^2 (m^2 -1)(m^2 -4)(m^2 -9) \dots (m^2 -(m-1)^2)$$

Notice, $(2m)!$ will contain primes of the form $p_k =m \pm n \leq 2m$.  The number of such primes are $\pi(2m)$. Further, the $m$ and $n$ must be co-prime. Then the number of possible "slots" of the form $m \pm n$ which can house primes (disregarding $p_1 = 2$) are:

$$ S(m) =  \phi(2 m) -1 $$

To derive the above the following are considered:

$1$. If $m$ is even then $(m^2 - (\text{even})^2) = \text{even}$

$2$. $m$ is not a prime as mentioned before.

$3$. $m - (m-1)$ is cannot be a prime.

Now, if:

$$ \pi(2m) > \frac{S(m)}{2} $$

Then we can prove Goldbach's conjecture for that number as that would imply one of the slots $m+n = p_i$ has a corresponding slot housing a prime $m+n =p_k$. And thus, if add both of them:

$$ 2m = p_i + p_k$$

### Example

Consider $m = 15 = 3 \cdot 5$. After considering $30!$ eliminating "slots":

$$ S(15) =  (1-\frac{1}{3})(1-\frac{1}{5}) 30 - 1= 15 $$

where the remaining slots are:

$$ (m^2 -1),(m^2 -7^2),(m^2 -11^2),(m^2 -13^2),(m^2 -17^2),(m^2 -19^2),(m^2 -23^2),(m + 29) $$

However, the number of primes are $\pi(30) = 10$. Since, there are more primes than "slots" available for them. Then one of the slots of the form $m$.

Comment: This is hard to follow.  Are you claiming that $(2m)!$ can always be written as the sum of two primes?   Something else?  To be sure, it's not difficult to prove that lots and lots of numbers are the sum of two primes.

Comment: The definitions of $S, D$ are entirely unclear to me.

Comment: @lulu I am claiming $2m$ can be written as the sum of $2$ primes when the inequality (in the question) is satisfied

Comment: There is no inequality in the question title.  Please edit your post for clarity.  Maybe clean up the notation....why refer to $p_k$ when the expression you write does not depend on $k$?

Comment: @lulu sorry I meant underneath the question title: $ \pi(2m) > \frac{S(m)}{2} $

Comment: @lulu I write $p_k$ where $k$ is the'th prime. However, $k$ is unkown.

Comment: @MeesdeVries S(m) is defined by the formula. For example: $S(15) =2 (1-1/3)(1-1/5) \times 30 -1 = 15$. We get $3$ and $5$ since they are factors of $15$

Comment: Are you just saying that $S(m)=\varphi(2m)-1$, using the euler phi function?  It's extremely hard to follow what you have written...what is $i$, for instance?  are you only considering some of the primes which divide $m$?  Which ones?  Note, you also appear to be using the same notation (namely $p_j$) to refer to both primes dividing $m$ and primes less than $2m$.  I suggest rewriting the post entirely.

Comment: @lulu the $i$ is an arbitrary distinct prime which divides $m$. I'm considering all of the "primes which divide".

Comment: If $S(m)$ is something like a small constant times $\phi(m)$ or $\phi(2m)$ (where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function), then the answer to your question is "a small percentage": usually $\phi(m)$ is approximately some absolute constant times $m$, while $\pi(2m)$ is an absolute constant times $m/\log(m)$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries I think I just re-discovered the Euler totient function ... except mine disregards the factor of $2$.

Comment: Anyway I'll be making some massive edits

Comment: Just for perspective, let's consider the case when $m=q^2$, the square of a prime.  Then $\varphi(2q^2)=(q-1)q$ and $\pi(2q^2)\sim \frac {2q^2}{\ln(2q^2)}$.  It is clear that the former is a lot larger than the latter (even if you divide it by $2$).  You can easily investigate other specific forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Note, I didn't read the background, just the question.)

One has 
$$\pi(2x) \sim \frac{2x}{\log x}$$
by the prime number theorem and
and
$$\phi(x) \gg \frac{e^{-\gamma} x}{\log \log x}$$
by standard estimates (see the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function), so since the latter grows much faster there can only be finitely many integers satisfying your inequality (and this finite set has density zero, obviously). More precisely, one has:

$$\frac{n}{\phi(n)} \le e^{\gamma} \left( \log \log n + \frac{2.5}{e^{\gamma} \log \log n} \right)$$
for all $n \ge 3$ except for $n = 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23$,

(See Lemma 4 here: https://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin/zeta/grytczuk.pdf)

and
$$\pi(x) < 1.25506 \cdot \frac{x}{\log x}$$

for $x \ge 17$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and just from these inequalities (computing $\phi(223092870)$ by hand) we already get
$$\frac{\phi(2x) - 1}{2} > \pi(2x), \quad x > 10^6$$

But then the smaller examples one can check by computer, and find the inequality you want holds for exactly $649$ integers, the largest one being $45045$ with
$$\frac{\phi(90090) - 1}{2} = 8639.5 < 8726 = \pi(90090).$$

Answer (score 1):

We can rephrase your question as: for which $m$ does
$$
\pi(2m) \geq \frac{\phi(2 m)}{2}
$$
hold, or equivalentely
$$
\frac{\phi(2m)}{\pi(2m)} \leq 2.
$$
Now for large enough $m$, $\pi(m) \approx \frac{m}{\log(m)}$, so this inequality becomes (roughly speaking)
$$
\frac{\phi(2m)\log(m)}{m}  \leq 2.
$$
One expression for $\phi(k)$ is $k\prod_{p \mid k}\left(1-\frac1p\right)$, where the variable $p$ runs over the primes, so we can rewrite this as
$$
\log(m)\prod_{p \mid 2m}\left(1-\frac1p\right) \leq 1.
$$
Taking logarithms on both sides,
$$
\log(\log(m)) + \sum_{p \mid 2m}\log\left(1-\frac1p\right) \leq 0.
$$
For large $p$, $-\frac1p$ is a good approximation for $\log\left(1-\frac1p\right)$, so the question becomes
$$
\log(\log(m)) - \sum_{p \mid 2m} \frac1p \leq 0.
$$
Now a [standard approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_of_the_sum_of_the_reciprocals_of_the_primes) tells us that this last sum is approximately equal to $\log(\log(p))$ where $p$ is the largest prime in the sum. Clearly the largest prime in this sum will be much smaller than $m$, because we took the best case $m$: where $m$ is a product of lots of distinct small primes.

Thus your inequality should hold almost never.